# The top images and headers can go over my background image, but my other images and headers underneath won't

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm a beginner at HTML and CSS, I'm learning at school, and I've come across something weird? My first header and first two images within the , that my background image is in as well, are going over the background image, but the rest of the images and headers below the  aren't going over the background image and it's created a huge space. I have no idea what I'm doing...  For the background image I had used a ::before so I could get it to be semi-transparent, but as soon as I did that, the other headers created a space between the background image.  I'm not exactly sure how to explain this either.
[There's a huge space between the vines and the next header right below it and I want the header to go over top of the vines like the 'Home' header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsqEp.png) Ignore the white space; that's not from the website, the screenshot didn't work very well sorry.

Here's my code, I didn't include the other headers and paragraphs because it would be really long, sorry.  I can include it if it's needed though.  Also if it's not a problem can someone tell me how to get rid of the small space between the background image and the top of the page?  I can try to elaborate more if needed, I just don't know what else to put or explain.  Thank you so much :)

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:#52B69A;">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <div class= bg-img>
    <img class=poopoo src=http://herschelandmorris.weebly.com/uploads/1/2/4/8/12482634/_8172691.png width="90">&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;<h1 class=block >‧₊˚Home˚₊‧</h1>&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;<img class= ihateithere src=https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b9/71/d3/b971d38635b85b11a51915cfb9ead30b.png width= "90">
    </div>
    <br>
    <h2 class= h2 style="text-indent: 10px"><i>‧₊˚What is the Legend of Zelda?˚₊‧</i></h2><br>
   &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;<img style="border-color: #D9ED92; border-width: 5px;border-style: solid;" src=https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d9/7e/cc/d97ecc64e6e15e5042aeb177ec49c602.jpg width="350">&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;<img  class=toplink src=https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-9gAb_OOBJu8/XC_p48I1tfI/AAAAAAAAAi8/poOknwCpkicCnnVwe6tY_m_JSFf2Vq8MgCK4BGAYYCw/s1600/b94968899328eca265ed8ed722ec37bb.png width="90">
<p>paragraph<br> <br> paragraph <br> <br> paragraph <br> <br>paragraph</p>
    <h2 class=h2 style="text-indent: 10px" align=right><i>‧₊˚The Complete Timeline˚₊‧</i></h2> &ensp;&ensp; <br>
    &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;<img align=right src=https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b9/71/d3/b971d38635b85b11a51915cfb9ead30b.png width="100" class=ee > &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;<img align=right style="border-color: #D9ED92; border-width: 5px;border-style: solid;" src=https://static0.srcdn.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Zelda-Breath-Of-The-Wild-Hyrule-World-Overlook.jpg?q=50&fit=crop&w=740&h=370 width="350">&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;
    <br clear="all">
    <p>paragraph<br> <br>paragraph<br><br> paragraph <br><br> paragraph <br><br> paragraph <br><br> paragraph </p>
    <h2 class= h2 style="text-indent: 10px"><i>‧₊˚Quick BOTW Guide˚₊‧</i></h2> <br>
    &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;<img class=padding src=https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-bcpyysPfwro/XC_p48iBWjI/AAAAAAAAAi4/b-VBy9-uJdk6JcSkn4jsr1Fldr99wnvVgCK4BGAYYCw/s1600/Elma_Figurine.png width="100"> &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp; <img  style="border-color: #E6F3BA; border-width: 5px;border-style: solid;" src=http://oyster.ignimgs.com/mediawiki/apis.ign.com/the-legend-of-zelda-hd/4/4f/MB_Lynel_Parry.jpg width="350"> 
    <p>paragraph <br><br> paragraph <br><br> 
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <ul>
      <li>list:
      <li> no 1
      <li> no 2
        <ul>
         <li> a
         <li> b
         <li> c 
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <p>paragraph <br><br>
    paragraph <br><br>
    &ensp;&ensp; paragraph <br><br>
    &ensp;&ensp; paragraph <br><br>
    &ensp;&ensp; paragraph<br><br>
    &ensp;&ensp; paragraph  <br><br>
    &ensp;&ensp; paragraph<br><br>
    &ensp;&ensp; paragraph <br><br>
    &ensp;&ensp; paragraph <br><br>
    &ensp;&ensp; paragraph <br><br>
    &ensp;&ensp; paragraph <br><br>
    &ensp;&ensp; paragraph </p>
      <ul>
        <li> no 1
        <li> no 2
        <li> no 3
      </ul>
    <p>paragraph<br><br>
    paragraph</p> 
      <ul>
        <li>1
        <li>2
        <li>3
        <li>4
      <ul> <br>
     </p> <br>`


h1 {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;  
  background:#B5E48C;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 158px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
.h2 {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  background-color: #99D98C;
  position: relative;
}
p {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
ul {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  }

.ee {
  margin-top: 85px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.padding {
  padding: 10px;
}
.mm {
  padding: 20px;
}
.eat {
  padding:20px;
}
.toplink {
  padding-bottom: 20px
}
.silent {
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-right: 7px;
}
.img-container {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
.poopoo {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
.bg-img {
  position: relative; 
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.bg-img::before {  
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://www.vippng.com/png/full/41-414789_green-plant-plants-png-pngstickers-border-watercolour-leaves.png");
  position: absolute; 
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  background-position: 50% 50%; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover; 
  -moz-background-size: cover; 
  -o-background-size: cover; 
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.75 ;
  }
.ihateithere {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the rest of the heading and images code inside the `.bg-img` div tag, because the background is inside `.bg-img` div tag, but the heading and images code are outside.

I update your code with additional updates on `position`, `z-index` for some of the elements. I also added `flex-direction: column` to `.bg-img` to make the content drops into rows.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  background: #B5E48C;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 158px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.h2 {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  background-color: #99D98C;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

ul {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.ee {
  margin-top: 85px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.padding {
  padding: 10px;
}

.mm {
  padding: 20px;
}

.eat {
  padding: 20px;
}

.toplink {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  padding-bottom: 20px
}

.silent {
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-right: 7px;
}

.img-container {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.poopoo {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.bg-img {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bg-img:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://www.vippng.com/png/full/41-414789_green-plant-plants-png-pngstickers-border-watercolour-leaves.png");
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.ihateithere {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="background-color:#52B69A;">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <div class="bg-img">
    <img class="poopoo" src=http://herschelandmorris.weebly.com/uploads/1/2/4/8/12482634/_8172691.png width="90">&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;
    <h1 class="block">‧₊˚Home˚₊‧</h1>&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;<img class="ihateithere" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b9/71/d3/b971d38635b85b11a51915cfb9ead30b.png" width="90">
    <br>
    <h2 class="h2" style="text-indent: 10px"><i>‧₊˚What is the Legend of Zelda?˚₊‧</i></h2><br> &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;
    <img style="position:relative;z-index:1;border-color: #D9ED92; border-width: 5px;border-style: solid;" src=https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d9/7e/cc/d97ecc64e6e15e5042aeb177ec49c602.jpg width="350">&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;<img class="toplink" src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-9gAb_OOBJu8/XC_p48I1tfI/AAAAAAAAAi8/poOknwCpkicCnnVwe6tY_m_JSFf2Vq8MgCK4BGAYYCw/s1600/b94968899328eca265ed8ed722ec37bb.png" width="90">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi again, I tried running it with your script with the rest of my text and it just shoved everything up... I think I should have included my other text code? I didn't include it because it was a lot of writing, but this is what I had without so much writing:

Comment: sorry it cut off I meant to say I put the rest of the code i had and edited my html coding

Comment: If you're familiar with https://jsfiddle.net/. You can put your code there and send me the URL, then I can take a look and give you advice.

Comment: ok thank you so much, here's the url https://jsfiddle.net/6bgq5djL/

Comment: Here you are https://jsfiddle.net/dqo3c71p/5/. I updated your code to make it work. 

Some more feedback.
- Attribute value should be in quote. Ex: `class="bg-img"`
- Remember to close your tags. Ex: `<li>content</li>`